# string is not displayed when converting binary to string

Tags: c#, string, binary, ascii

I have some problem and i can not define the reasons.

I have function to decrypt some info, the return value is a string that converted from binary to string.

```
public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string completeEncodedKey, int keySize)
    {

        RijndaelManaged aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged();
        aesEncryption.KeySize = keySize;
        aesEncryption.BlockSize = 128;
        aesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        aesEncryption.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedKey)).Split(',')[0]);
        aesEncryption.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedKey)).Split(',')[1]);
        ICryptoTransform decrypto = aesEncryption.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(encryptedText.ToCharArray(), 0, encryptedText.Length);// convert the cipertext to binary
        string RESULT = (string)ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypto.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length));//convert the binary to string

        return RESULT;
     }
```

The problem appears when i call this function and get the result, and then try to display the result with additional strings, for example by this message box:

```
 String result= function.Decrypt(textToBeDecrypted, key, 128);


MessageBox.Show("This is sample text " + result + " here i want to append another string ");
```

ONLY APPENDED TEXT (IN THIS EXAMPLE: " here i want to append another string ") IS NOT DISPLAYED

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Use a debugger. Step through `Decrypt`. Check values along the way. Find the issue.

Comment: result Value is displayed well and it returned as what I expect. But when i append another text, this new text is not displayed.

Comment: So you mean `here i want to append another string` is not displayed?

Comment: exactly that what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string result = function.Decrypt(textToBeDecrypted, key, 128).Replace("\0", string.Empty);
```

Comment: and @Jonesy Thank you for highlighting the problem ! :) thank you very much

Comment: @hum. I see you've never upvoted/accepted before -- please don't forget to upvote/accept whatever answer you feel best solved your problem. Glad to help.

Comment: sweet i wasn't sure that a simple replace would work.  Glad it did.

Answer (score 1):

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/275256-rijndael-decrypt-returning-escape-characters-end-string

seems like the same issue.  I bet you have an escape character (\0) on the end.

Comment: it makes sense,, I will explore the characters of the return string

Answer (score 1):

```
aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
```

You added zeros on the end of your message... and zeros end the string as far as the Win32 MessageBox API is concerned.

Remove the padding during decryption (using a different padding mode makes this easier).